# How can I provide dynamic values for an 'extend'? (or 'how does extend work in this case' ?)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ember.js, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

I'm looking at a `class` ([this one](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader/blob/master/addon/uploaders/uploader.js)). The [doco for it suggests you can `extend` the class to change a property of the class](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader#modifying-the-request). That is true, it works for me.

However what I want to do is dynamically provide the values for the setting.

I've got two questions.

**First**

How can I adapt [the demo](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader#modifying-the-request) so that I can dynamically supply the values used.

**Second**

I realise when I look at the class, this seems to be the significant part of the code ...

```
  ajax (url, data = {}, method = this.method) {
    const ajaxSettings = assign(
      {},
      {
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: () => {
          const xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
          xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
            this.didProgress(event);
          };
          this.one('isAborting', () => xhr.abort());
          return xhr;
        },
        url,
        data,
        method
      },
      get(this, 'ajaxSettings')
    );

    return this.ajaxPromise(ajaxSettings);
  },
```

... I'm not confident that I understand how the 'extend' is doing what it's doing . `ajaxSettings` is used within the `ajax` function so how does the `extend` reach within the function and merge the value provided in the extend into the hardcoded values in the function ?

Hope the question makes sense ... I'll happily settle for an answer to 'First' if you can't manage 'Second' without writing a book ;-)

---

In response to comments

- the `extend` is defined here https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.8/functions/@ember%2Fobject/extend and
- `get` is defined here https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.8/functions/@ember%2Fobject/get .

Comment: Can you post the definitions of `extend` and `get`?

Comment: @Bergi : thanks for your comment, I have now got a resolution of this but I will edit the question to include those definitions for the use of others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It looks like you can simply make `ajaxSettings` a computed property if you want to set it dynamically:

```
import Uploader from 'ember-uploader/uploaders/uploader';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Uploader.extend({
  ajaxSettings: computed('someProperty', function() {
    // do your logic to set the options dynamically in here
    return {
      headers: {
        'X-Application-Name': 'Uploader Test'
      }
    };
  })
});
```

2. That indeed is where the `ajaxSettings` property is being used and the key line of code is this one:

```
get(this, 'ajaxSettings')
```

Which retrieves the `ajaxSettings` property from the class (thus, if `ajaxSettings` was set on the base class your subclass will override the base class settings -- see [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/classes-and-instances/) for more info on extends).

That line is used in conjunction with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (technically [Ember's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) to build the options. This part provides some defaults:

```
{
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  xhr: () => {
    const xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
      this.didProgress(event);
    };
    this.one('isAborting', () => xhr.abort());
      return xhr;
    },
    url,
    data,
    method
  }
}
```

but since the retrieval of `ajaxSettings` occurs after the defaults, any properties specified in your class' `ajaxSettings` object which overlap with the above defaults will take precedence and override them.

So if you defined `contentType` in your class' `ajaxSettings` like so:

```
ajaxSettings: computed('someProperty', function() {
  return {
    contentType: true, // (or some other value besides false)
    ...
  };
})
```

That would overlap with the `contentType: false` specified in the default values above and since it would get merged through `assign()` after the defaults, it would take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the 'computed' suggestion and the excellent answer to the second part of my question.